# Lombok @builder on a class that extends another class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lombok

I have two classes `Child` extends `Parent`. I need to put @Builder annotation on the classes such that I do not need to create the builder my self.

```
package jerry;// Internal compiler error: java.lang.NullPointerException

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;

@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Builder))
public class Child extends Parent { 
//Multiple markers at this line
//  - Implicit super constructor Parent() is undefined. Must explicitly invoke another constructor
//  - overrides java.lang.Object.toString

   private String a;
   private int b;
   private boolean c;

}


@Builder
public class Parent {
    private double d;
    private float e;
}
```

I need to be able to build child instance such that

```
Child child = Child.builder().a("aVal").b(1000).c(true).d(10.1).e(20.0F).build();
```

But so far I am getting the errors mentioned in side that code comments. Can any one point me to the right direction how to achieve it with lombok or any other similar library ?

**Sub-question**

Why does `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Autowired))` compile but `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Builder))` does not?

Comment: I am trying to evaluate https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/1337/commits currently.

Answer (score 111):

Since release 1.18.2 lombok includes [the new experimental `@SuperBuilder`](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder). It supports fields from superclasses (also abstract ones). With it, the solution is as simple as this:

```
@SuperBuilder
public class Child extends Parent {
   private String a;
   private int b;
   private boolean c;
}

@SuperBuilder
public class Parent {
    private double d;
    private float e;
}

Child instance = Child.builder().b(7).e(6.3).build();
```

*Update 2019-10-09:* If you use IntelliJ, you need at least version 0.27 of the IntelliJ Lombok plugin to use `@SuperBuilder`.

PS: `@AllArgsConstructor(onConstructor=@__(@Builder))` does not work because `@Builder` is an annotation-processing annotation that lombok translates to code during compilation. Generating and then translating new lombok annotation would require several iterations of annotation processing, and lombok does not support that. `@Autowired`, in contrast, is a regular Java annotation available at runtime.

Comment: Just a word of warning though: not supported on IntelliJ Lombok plugin yet.

Comment: The current release 0.27 of the IntelliJ Lombok plugin now supports `@SuperBuilder`.

Comment: Does not work on extending super classes with Generic Types unless you upgrade to 1.18.16

https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2359

Comment: There is still two limitations. First you can't use `@Builder` with `@SuperBuilder` in a hierarchy, And next, all of ancestor classes must use `@SuperBuilder`, so you can't extend from a third-party class which didn't use this annotation. @jan-rieke

Comment: Yes. Those limitations are also mentioned in the documentation. For a workaround for the 3rd-party-extension issue see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708752/using-lomboks-superbuilder-concept-on-a-class-extended-from-a-3rd-party-librar/61763012#61763012

Answer (score 61):

See in https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2016/05/reducing-boilerplate-code-project-lombok/ (*@Builder and inheritance* part)

Adjusted to your classes

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Parent {
  private double d;
  private float e;
}

public class Child extends Parent {
  private String a;
  private int b;
  private boolean c;

  @Builder
  public Child(String a, int b, boolean c, double d, float e) {
    super(d, e);
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

With this setup

```
Child child = Child.builder().a("aVal").b(1000).c(true).d(10.1).e(20.0F).build();
```

works correctly

Comment: Good point I did try that ... But I can not provide more than 7 params to any function which is a code convention in my team and build fails if I provide more than 7 params. My original code has more than 30 fields in super / parent class

Comment: I don't know if it can be done without listing all the parent + child fields in the child constructor/@Builder, at least I did not find any such examples. As a workaround, you might consider to suppress this code convention for this particular class (at least I suppose it comes from some static code analyzer tool, like PMD, Findbugs, Sonar and such as can be suppressed)

Comment: Won't work if parent class also has @Builder annotation

Comment: @ShrikantPrabhu in that case, where I am now, I just abort the inheritance and copy the fields; it is lucky that there are just several field in common.

Comment: This solution also works great when you are extending from parent class that cant be modified!!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 14):

You need to use `@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)` in every object.

```
@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Parent extends Child {
}

@Data
@SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
public class Child {
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check

Comment: it was be checked. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar but slightly different use case. In my case, I have a chain of abstract super classes that build and execute requests. Different requests share some common parameters, but not every request supports all parameters. The builders for concrete requests should only provide methods for setting supported parameters for a given request.

I started out with the constructor-based builder implementations, but this resulted in too much boilerplate code, especially if you have many fields to be configured. I have now come up with the following solutions, which looks much cleaner to me.

Basically the concrete subclasses define the actual fields that the Builder should support, and the Getter annotation results in the corresponding superclass methods to be overridden. The getters in the abstract superclasses can even be defined as abstract to require concrete implementations to define those fields.

```
public abstract class AbstractSuperClass1 {
    protected String getParamA() { return "defaultValueA"; }

    public final void doSomething() {
        System.out.println(getParamA());
        doSomeThingElse();
    }

    protected abstract void doSomeThingElse();
}
```

---

```
public abstract class AbstractSuperClass2 extends AbstractSuperClass1 {
    protected String getParamB() { return "defaultValueB"; }

    protected void doSomeThingElse() {
        System.out.println(getParamB());
    }
}
```

---

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) @Builder
public class ConcreteClass1 extends AbstractSuperClass2 {
    private final String paramA;
    // Not supported by this implementation: private final String paramB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteClass1.builder()
           .paramA("NonDefaultValueA")
           .build().doSomething();
    }
}
```

---

```
import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;

@Getter(AccessLevel.PROTECTED) @Builder
public class ConcreteClass2 extends AbstractSuperClass2 {
    private final String paramA;
    private final String paramB;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConcreteClass2.builder()
            .paramA("NonDefaultValueA").paramB("NonDefaultValueB")
            .build().doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if your child class wants to have a builder method when the parent already have one,then you can create an all args constructor for the child class and then annotate builder on the constructor of child class and set the property

> @Builder(builderMethodName = "custombuildername")

Then invoke the customname builder while creating the child class Object.

```
package jerry;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;

public class Child extends Parent { 

   private String a;
   private int b;
   private boolean c;

   @Builder(builderMethodName = "childBuilder")
   public Child(String a, int b, boolean c, double d, float e){
       super(d,e);
   }

}


@Builder
public class Parent {
    private double d;
    private float e;
}
```