# Using Lombok's @SuperBuilder concept on a class extended from a 3rd party library

Tags: spring-boot, lombok

I have a class hierarchy as below.

Child --> Parent --> SuperParent

Since the **Child** class has extended the **Parent** class I have to use Lombok's `@SuperBuilder` annotation instead of the `@Builder`. Also, as far as I know, all the superclasses need to have the `@SuperBuilder` annotation. But in my case, the **SuperParent** class comes from an external library, where I cannot add the `@SuperBuilder` annotation. I am getting the below compilation error.

```
The constructor SuperParent(DocumentUploadedResponseDto.DocumentUploadedResponseDtoBuilder<capture#1-of ?,capture#2-of ?>) is undefined.
```

Any solution or an alternative for this? Thank you.

Comment: *it requires that all superclasses also have the @SuperBuilder annotation*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bit ugly, but it's possible. You have to insert a helper class into your inheritance chain between `Parent` and `SuperParent`; let's call it `SuperParentBuilderEnabler`. In this class, you have to manually implement all neccessary builder elements. Especially, you have to write all setter methods for the fields from `SuperParent`.
This will allow the `Parent` and `Child` classes to simply use a `@SuperBuilder` annotation without any further modifications.

I assume that `SuperParent` has an `int superParentField` field, just to demonstrate how you can write such a setter method in the builder class. Furthermore, I assume that this field can be set via constructor argument. Here is what you have to do:

```java
public abstract class SuperParentBuilderEnabler extends SuperParent {
    public static abstract class SuperParentBuilderEnablerBuilder<C extends SuperParentBuilderEnabler, B extends SuperParentBuilderEnablerBuilder<C, B>> {
        private int superParentField;

        public B superParentField(int superParentField) {
            this.superParentField = superParentField;
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract B self();

        public abstract C build();
    }

    protected SuperParentBuilderEnabler(SuperParentBuilderEnablerBuilder<?, ?> b) {
        super(b.superParentField);
    }
}
```

Now let `Parent extend SuperParentBuilderEnabler` and you're done.

Comment: hmmm...If there is no other solution I think I will have to try your 'ugly' but nice solution.

Comment: Today I implemented your solution. It is perfectly working. Thank you very much for helping.

Comment: I think that a less ugly solution would be writing setter and getter field by field :)

Comment: Well, that depends. You are giving up immutability, and that can be ugly or bug-prone as well. And if you are designing an API, that may likely be worse than just a bit of internal "ugly" code.

Answer (score 3):

I'm sharing how I applied the accepted answer for [`RepresentationModel`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/api/org/springframework/hateoas/RepresentationModel.html).

```java
abstract class BaseTypeParent<T extends BaseTypeParent<T>>
        extends RepresentationModel<T> {

    protected abstract static class BaseTypeParentBuilder<
            T extends BaseTypeParent<T>,
            C extends BaseTypeParent<T>,
            B extends BaseTypeParentBuilder<T, C, B>
            > {

        protected abstract B self();

        public abstract C build();
    }

    protected BaseTypeParent(final BaseTypeParentBuilder<T, ?, ?> b) {
        super();
    }
}
```