# Lombok @Builder with inheritance that requires a certain field

Tags: java, lombok

Java 11, Spring Boot and Lombok here. I am trying to build up a hierarchy of objects extending Spring's [`ApplicationEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationEvent.html#ApplicationEvent-java.lang.Object-) class which forces me to provide a constructor:

```
public ApplicationEvent(Object source) {
   ...
}
```

So extending `ApplicationEvent` I have a `TrackedEvent` that is an abstract base class for my other events to build off:

```
public abstract class TrackedEvent extends ApplicationEvent {

    private String correlationId;
    private String description;
    // ... lots of fields here

}
```

One of the (many) events extending `TrackedEvent` is `OperationalEvent`:

```
public class OperationalEvent extends TrackedEvent {

    private OperationType type;
    private OperationStatus status;
    // ... several more fields here

}
```

Other than the `source : Object` field, which is **required** by the grandparent `ApplicationEvent` constructor, all other `TrackedEvent` and `OperationalEvent` fields are optional. So because there are so many fields here to populate and instantiation-time, I feel the **Builder Pattern** is appropriate. So I'd like to employ Lombok's `@Builder` annotation (and possibly other annos) to obtain an API *something* like so:

```
OperationalEvent opsEvent = OperationalEvent.Builder(this)
    .description("something happened")
    .status(OperationalStatus.THE_THING)
    .build();
```

My thinking here is we would pass `this` in as a required builder constructor argument (to satisfy `ApplicationEvent`'s constructor for `source : Object`...somehow) and then use the `@Builder` like normal.

Is this possible to do in Lombok, and if so, how?

As a fallback I can just write my own builders but since I have so many subclasses it would be great to leverage Lombok if at all possible.

Comment: You can use `@SuperBuilder` together with an intermediate abstract class as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763012/10026074

Comment: Not when the grandparent class forces a constructor with a required argument

Comment: I think you can. I added another answer describing how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't use `@SuperBuilder` annotation, beacause you don't have access to `ApplicationEvent` class, as far as I can see, the only solution is to do something like following:

Assume that you have `TrackedEvent` class wich looks something like this:

```
public class TrackedEvent extends ApplicationEvent {
    protected String correlationId;
    protected String description;

    public TrackedEvent(Object source, String correlationId, String description) {
        super(source);
        this.correlationId = correlationId;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public TrackedEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }


}
```

And you have `OperationalEvent` class wich extends above class.
Than, you can implement builder pattern in OptionalEvent class like this:

```
public class OperationalEvent extends TrackedEvent {

    private String type;
    private String status;

    public OperationalEvent(Object source) {
        super(source);
    }


    @Builder(builderMethodName = "optionalEvent")
    public OperationalEvent(Object source, String correlationId, String description, String type, String status) {
        super(source, correlationId, description);
        this.type = type;
        this.status = status;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "OperationalEvent{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                "correlationId:" + correlationId +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And than the following code should work as expected:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationEvent applicationEvent = new ApplicationEvent(new Object()) {
        @Override
        public Object getSource() {
            return super.getSource();
        }
    };
    OperationalEvent opsEvent = OperationalEvent.optionalEvent()
            .description("something happened")
            .source(applicationEvent)
            .status("status")
            .correlationId("1")
            .build();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Nemanja (+1) -- 2 initial questions if you don't mind: **(1)** is there any way to pass `this` (the object where we're instantiating the `OperationEvent` inside of) into the `applicationEvent` source field? And **(2)** just verifying so I understand the builder API better: is that a typo you have? Did you mean `builderMethodName = "operationalEvent"`, or did you actually mean to write `optionalEvent`? Thanks again so much!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup you can pass this reference as argument for .source() method but keep in mind that object which reference you are passing should be instance of ApplicationEvent. As for second question,yes I made typo. It should be "operationalEvent", but the name doesn't really matters, since that's just name of builder, you can name it whatever you like, but I agree, in this case more appropriate name would be "operationalEvent" as you wrote. I'm glad if I helped. Cheers!

Comment: OK thanks again @Nemanja, one last followup question (I promise!) -- the `source` of an `ApplicationEvent` is _not_ intended on being another `ApplicationEvent`, the `source` is supposed to be whatever class instance originated the event. So if I publish an `ApplicationEvent` to the Spring event bus from inside, say, a `WidgetService`, then `source` would be the reference to the `WidgetService`. Is there any way to accommodate this in your proposed design? As always, thanks again!

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup Now I looked a little better, I made a mistake in the previous comment. Since in class OperationalEvent source property is type of Object class, not just ApplicationEvent class, you should be able to pass any object to .source() method. As far as I can see that should work without issues. Cheers

Comment: I just confirmed this works beautifully, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@SuperBuilder` together with an intermediate abstract class, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61763012/10026074).

The advantage over using customized `@Builder`s is that you only have to manually implement this single custom intermediate class once. There is no need for customization in every subclass.

In this case, the intermediate class looks as follows:

```
public abstract class ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnabler extends ApplicationEvent {

    public static abstract class ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnablerBuilder<C extends ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnabler, B extends ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnablerBuilder<C, B>> {
        private Object source;

        public B source(Object source) {
            this.source = source;
            return self();
        }

        protected abstract B self();

        public abstract C build();
    }

    protected ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnabler(ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnablerBuilder<?, ?> b) {
        super(b.source);
    }
}
```

Next, let all your direct subclasses extend `ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnabler` (instead of `ApplicationEvent`) and put a `@SuperBuilder` on all classes:

```
@SuperBuilder
public abstract class TrackedEvent extends ApplicationEventSuperBuilderEnabler { ... }

@SuperBuilder
public class OperationalEvent extends TrackedEvent { ... }
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
OperationalEvent opsEvent = OperationalEvent.builder()
        .source(this)
        .description("something happened")
        .status(OperationalStatus.THE_THING)
        .build();
```