# Inhertance class annotated by @Builder

Tags: java, spring, lombok

I need to inherit a super class from a dependency that has @Builder annotation (I can't modify this class) at the same time I want my sub class to have the builder pattern. I tried to use the @builder and @SuperBuilder annotations in my subclass but both throw an error.

Comment: `@SuperBuilder` is designed for exactly this case. Did you read its [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder)? If so, what error are you getting?

Comment: If the super cannot be modified, then consider using composition instead of inheritance, with manually generated getter methods.  Or manually create your own builder method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Lombok's @SuperBuilder concept on a class extended from a 3rd party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61708752/using-lomboks-superbuilder-concept-on-a-class-extended-from-a-3rd-party-librar)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder):

> @SuperBuilder also works with fields from superclasses. (...) It requires that all superclasses also have the @SuperBuilder annotation.

You mentioned that you cannot change the superclass. If that class is annotated only with `@Builder`, you cannot use `@SuperBuilder` with a subclass. You'll have to migrate the parent to `@SuperBuilder` as well.

Alternatively, you can use composition instead of inheritance, and include the parent class as a property instead of a superclass.