# JPA inheritance strategy JOINED: Connot access superclass attributes

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, builder

I am working on a project and I have to implement a class hierarchy. For example, a typical Person hierarchy.

I have an abstract superclass `Person` and its subclasses `Student`.

Superclass **Person**:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(
       name = "persons"
       uniqueConstraints = {
                @UniqueConstraint(name = "persons_name_unique", columnNames = "name")
        })
public abstract class Person extends AbstractPersistable<Long>{
    @Getter
    private String name;
    @Getter
    private int age;
    
    // ...
}
```

Subclass **Student**:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PROTECTED)
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student extends Person {
    @Getter
    private int grade;

    // ...
}
```

**Problem**:

My issue is that I cannot access the attributes of the superclass when I am using the `.builder()`.

```
Student student =
         Student.builder()
                .name("UniqueName") //CompilerError(Cannot resolve method 'name' in 'StudentBuilder')
                .age(19)
                .grade(2)
                .build();
```

However, when I remove `@Builder` from the superclass `Person` I can access only the attributes of the superclass and none of the subclass.
And when I romove `@Builder` from the subclass and keep it in the superclass it's the other way around.

My question is what am I doing wrong - I believe it's because of the `@Builder` annotation, what's the correct representation of `@Builder`

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. Either create builder constructor that calls the parent  constructor, so something like:

```
@Builder
public Student(String name, int age, int grade) {
    super(name, age);
    this.grade = grade;
}
```

in your student (and remove the class level @Builder). You also need to expand visibility of `Person` `@AllArgsConstructor` at least to to protected. See [this](https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance).

Another option is to use Lombok `@SuperBuilder` (package experimental but seems to works). Just replace `@Builder` in both of your classes with `@SuperBuilder`.

Comment: thanks I am going with the @SuperBuilder; however, now I am getting this Error(`cannot find symbol class AbstractPersistableBuilder`) when building the project

Comment: @user17441315 I believe this error has not much to do with Lombok but something like incomplete clean before build and/or problem with your imports.

Comment: It does. Because when using `@SuperBuilder` all parent and child classes have to be mapped also as `@SuperBuilder`. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Annotating both the parent and the child class with `@SuperBuilder` should be one way to make all attributes available:

- https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/SuperBuilder
- [Lombok @builder on a class that extends another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948858/lombok-builder-on-a-class-that-extends-another-class)

Comment: Thank you but now when I build my project I am getting this Error: java cannot find symbol class abstractpersistable builder